# Magento - Order summary onepage checkout

Tags: magento, checkout, summary

I'm working on a Magento site, which is using the Magento's onepage checkout.

I need to show an order summary on the right hand side of the checkout process (instead of the "your checkout process block")

The summary ideally will need to consist of;
Product name, quantity and price
With the sub total, delivery cost and grand total prices underneath.

Comment: Isn't that allready implemented? If you don't want to show the other blocks like shipping address and so on then comment them out in the checkout.xml (layout file)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's implemented. 
I can take care of the other bits, that's not a problem - But by default, atleast, I don't have my order summary in the checkout section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in my checkout.xml

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>


        <reference name="head">
            <remove name="cookielawHead" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="cookielawFooter" />
        </reference>



        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <!--
        <remove name="right"/>
        -->



        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-checkout.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChildren"></action> 

            <!--<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" before="-" name="catalog.cart.sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/> -->

            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="ajaxCart" template="ajaxcart/cart/sidebarcheckout.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>


            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="total_sidebar" as="total_sidebar" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals_right.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>    

            <block type="cms/block" name="checkout_contact_right">
                   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>checkout_contact_right</block_id></action>
            </block>            
            <block type="cms/block" name="checkout_shipping_right">
                   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>checkout_shipping_right</block_id></action>
            </block>

        </reference>

         <reference name="content">
             <block type="checkout/onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="checkout/onepage.phtml">
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml">
                     <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.onepage.login.before" as="login_before" translate="label">
                         <label>Login/Registration Before</label>
                         <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                     </block>
                 </block>
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping_method" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                     <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                     <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
                 </block>
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                     <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                         <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
                     </block>
                 </block>
                 <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml"/>
             </block>
         </reference>

    </checkout_onepage_index>
```

This will add the cart and the totals on the right side of the checkout.

Comment: Will give it a go in a moment. Thank you :)